# Magento 2.1.6 custom theme page layouts broken

Tags: magento2, layout, page-layouts, magento2.1.6

### Magento 2.1.6 custom theme page layouts broken

Hi, I have my theme set up and working correctly but now I want to add a custom homepage layout.
I have set it up like so:

Sulman

....Sulmantheme

........Magento_Theme

............page_layout

................custom_home.xml

............layouts.xml

**layouts.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<page_layouts xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/PageLayout/etc/layouts.xsd">
    <layout id="custom_home">
        <label translate="true">Custom Home</label>
    </layout>
</page_layouts>
```

**custom_home.xml:** (copied from 1column.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_layout.xsd">
    <update handle="empty"/>
    <referenceContainer name="page.wrapper">
        <container name="header.container" as="header_container" label="Page Header Container"  htmlTag="header" htmlClass="page-header" before="main.content"/>
        <container name="page.top" as="page_top" label="After Page Header" after="header.container"/>
        <container name="footer-container" as="footer" before="before.body.end" label="Page Footer Container" htmlTag="footer" htmlClass="page-footer" />
    </referenceContainer>
</layout>
```

The new custom page layout can now be selected in the CMS page:

[image]

I then clear cache and deploy static content.

But when I visit the page in the browser it is blank. 
When I view source I see the bare bones html, which is coming from /vendor/magento/module-theme/view/base/templates/root.phtml

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-GB">
    <head >
        <script>
    var require = {
        "baseUrl": "http://sulman.local/pub/static/version1494324423/frontend/Sulman/Sulmantheme/en_GB"
    };
</script>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
<meta name="description" content="lorem ipsum"/>
<meta name="keywords" content="lorem ipsum"/>
<meta name="robots" content="NOINDEX,NOFOLLOW"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
<title></title>
<link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  media="all" href="http://sulman.local/pub/static/version1494324423/frontend/Sulman/Sulmantheme/en_GB/mage/calendar.css" />
<link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  media="all" href="http://sulman.local/pub/static/version1494324423/frontend/Sulman/Sulmantheme/en_GB/css/styles-m.css" />
<link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  media="screen and (min-width: 768px)" href="http://sulman.local/pub/static/version1494324423/frontend/Sulman/Sulmantheme/en_GB/css/styles-l.css" />
<link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  media="print" href="http://sulman.local/pub/static/version1494324423/frontend/Sulman/Sulmantheme/en_GB/css/print.css" />
<link  rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="http://sulman.local/pub/static/version1494324423/frontend/Sulman/Sulmantheme/en_GB/Magento_Theme/favicon.ico" />
<link  rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="http://sulman.local/pub/static/version1494324423/frontend/Sulman/Sulmantheme/en_GB/Magento_Theme/favicon.ico" />
<script  type="text/javascript"  src="http://sulman.local/pub/static/version1494324423/frontend/Sulman/Sulmantheme/en_GB/requirejs/require.js"></script>
            </head>
    <body data-container="body" data-mage-init='{"loaderAjax": {}, "loader": { "icon": "http://sulman.local/pub/static/version1494324423/frontend/Sulman/Sulmantheme/en_GB/images/loader-2.gif"}}' class="cms-page-view page-layout-custom-home">
            </body>
</html>
```

It seems like no content is being loaded??
Any one have a clue? Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

You have created wrong directory structure 
Please follow the folder structure below to get the desired output

```
Sulman

....Sulmantheme

........Magento_Theme

............view

.................frontend

....................page_layout

........................custom_home.xml   

....................layouts.xml
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm pretty sure those paths are incorrect. I tried them but now the new layout doesn't even show up in the admin.

Comment: Please refer vendor\magento\module-theme\view\frontend for further reference

Comment: I appreciate your help but  I don't think you are correct. Google shows nothing to suggest your paths are correct. Also the path you gave for me to check is for a module? I am referring to a theme.

Comment: Please see official Magento docs: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/layout-extend.html

Comment: please refer my new answer below

Answer (score 0):

Path **app\design\frontend{{Vendor}}{{Theme}}\Magento_Theme\page_layout** create file
**custom_home.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_layout.xsd">
    <update handle="empty"/>
    <referenceContainer name="page.wrapper">
        <container name="header.container" as="header_container" label="Page Header Container"  htmlTag="header" htmlClass="page-header" before="main.content"/>
        <container name="page.top" as="page_top" label="After Page Header" after="header.container"/>
        <container name="footer-container" as="footer" before="before.body.end" label="Page Footer Container" htmlTag="footer" htmlClass="page-footer" />
    </referenceContainer>
</layout>
```

This will be the reference to your new layout.
Now initialize the new layout to your theme

in the directroy **app\design\frontend{{Vendor}}{{Theme}}\Magento_Theme**

**layouts.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<page_layouts xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/PageLayout/etc/layouts.xsd">
    <layout id="custom_home">
        <label translate="true">Custom Home</label>
    </layout>
</page_layouts>
```

Comment: That is exactly what I have put in my original question that isn't working!? Have I missed something?! I even copied and pasted your code juts in case I had a typo somewhere. Nope. Exactly the same output...